# AgGrid SSRM: detect if page data was loaded from AgGrid's internal store (cache) or from endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using AgGrid SSRM v29.3.5 with pagination. Whenever i navigate to a new page the `getRows` method gets invoked in order to fetch new data from the backend. When i re-visit a page the data will be loaded from AgGrid's internal cache.

My questions is this: is there a way to detect if the data was freshly loaded via `getRows` or from AgGrid's internal store (or cache if you want). I looked over the documentation and haven't seen such a method. The only thing that comes close is `getCacheBlockState` but it would be really helpful to have something that informs if data for a page has been loaded from the internal AgGrid cache or not. Something like `isRowDataLoadedFromCache`.

I'm aware that i could use CSRM because it does not use caching but it's a bit difficult to make the switch now because that would be a big effort for our team.

Thank you in advance for any answers!